# Diffrences in code from my WYSIWYG

Tags: javascript, jquery, wysiwyg, execcommand

I create the simplest WYSIWYG editor, but in each browser generated other html code.
I use:
        `a.execCommand('useCSS', false, true);
        a.execCommand('styleWithCSS', false, false);`
For example:
Chrome generate unnecessary div when i use enter key...
IE generate `<p>` tags when go to new line...
Firefox generate for me the best code, inserts old br:)

I must create styles for results, by it's too much differences.

Comment: *Which* editor are you using? *What code* do you use to obtain and manipulate the contents?

Comment: Browser differences with `contenteditable` is way too much trouble to try to hack about yourself. I would suggest to use TinyMCE or a comparable ready-made solution. http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The insertion of div's, p's, or br's when pressing enter/return is NOT controlled with the useCSS/styleWithCSS option. This option is only for *styles*. What happens when you press `enter/return` is entirely browser-specific. To normalize the behavior, you can code a key-handler for the return key (code 13) where you insert a `<br>` or `\n` or whatever you like when `enter` is pressed.

See the following questions to get started with writing a key handler for exactly this:

[Make a <br> instead of <div></div> by pressing Enter on a contenteditable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080529/make-a-br-instead-of-div-div-by-pressing-enter-on-a-contenteditable)

[Cross browser event handler must capture [ENTER]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748985/cross-browser-event-handler-must-capture-enter)